# Convert DXF file to JSON Geometry 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, three.js, dxf

I'm trying to use [Threejs.org](http://threejs.org). I need to upload my 3D DXF file and show it on my page using Threejs. But I have no idea how to convert it. [Dxf-parser](https://github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser) is working for 2D images only. Could you please help me find the solution how to convert my .dxf file to JSON geometry 4 which is used by three.js or any other solution.

My project is in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score -1):

There is this library, though I've not used it myself:
https://github.com/gdsestimating/three-dxf

If that doesn't work you'll probably need to convert to another format first (OBJ or JBX) then to JSON with the converters in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/converters